# Save a class instance on a Meteor reactive var

Tags: meteor

I created a Helper class with some methods. So I want to store this helper class instance in a reactive var to access this instance inside the html template.
Is that possible?

```
export class APIArticle {

    constructor(articleObj){
        if( !_.isUndefined(articleObj) && !_.isNull(articleObj) && _.isObject(articleObj) ){
            this.articleObj = new ReactiveObject(articleObj);
        } else {
            throw "impossible creation!!!! Article-Object or ArticleId is required!";
        }
    }

getCurrencyCode() {
        if( _.isUndefined(this.currencyCode) || _.isNull(this.currencyCode) ){
            try{
                this.currencyCode = this.articleObj.sellPrice[0].money.currencyCode.toUpperCase();
            }catch(e){
                this.currencyCode = "EUR";
            }
        }
        return this.currencyCode
    }

}
```

This my simple class. Now the Template Javascript.

```
Template.philosArticleCarousel.created = function(){
    let self = this;
    this.articleArray = new ReactiveArray();
    Meteor.call("articleList",function(err,succ){
        if(!err){
            self.articleArray.clear();
            _.each(succ,function(i){
                let apiArticle = new APIArticle(i);
                self.articleArray.push(apiArticle);
            });
        }
    });
};

Template.philosArticleCarousel.helpers({
    articleArray:() => { return Template.instance().articleArray.list(); }
});
```

The access in Template in an each loop with this.getCurrencyCode is empty. On printing this as JSON I see only the fields and no sign of being a instance.

Okay if I use a method which delivers a primitive all goes fine. But this deliver an object HOW I can access them?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you tried already to solve the provblem. Did any errors occur? Please add them, too.

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I never expected someone writes the code for me. It was a question. And maybe their is somewhere (which I not found) a page with exactly my issue and anyone here knows it. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this with your code and everything worked fine:

```
<template name="hello">
  <ul>
    {{#each article in articleArray}}
      <li>{{article.articleObj.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

Of course I had to make some assumptions, like that each article object would have a top level name property.

I even tested making the ReactiveArray global and adding a new instance and modifying the underlying ReactiveObject.

You can take a look at my example here: https://github.com/coagmano/stackoverflow-48810966

Comment: Hi, yes that works for me too! All fine.
But in the case I have a function getName with a parameter and my return is an object, HOW I can access them?

Comment: Example:
`{{ (article.articleObj.getName "param").getPlain }}`

Comment: Okay I figure out to use with! `{{#with function}}`